# ¿Por qué me cerraron la pregunta "Definición y diferencia de objeto e instancia en Java"?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, pregunta-específica

Hace poco formulé una pregunta y no sé por qué, pero a pesar de estar bien formulada (según yo) me dieron votos negativos y con ello no puedo hacer más preguntas por un determinado lapso de tiempo.

Por favor comprendan que recién tomo partido en este mundo autodidáctmente con 13 años.

Mi "mala pregunta" era [Definición y diferencia de objeto e instancia en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/236373/116948)

Comment: Buenas, viendo tu pregunta anterior te explico cómo podrías haber preguntado la misma pregunta y sea mejor recibida. Podrías haber puesto qué páginas /libros/foros leíste (citar lo que sea referido al problema) para intentar entender que es una instancia, podrías haber puesto un ejemplo de código donde manifiestes tu duda de qué es una instancia. Intenta hacer preguntas concisas y demuestra que has intentado por tus medios buscar una solución. Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: La pregunta que refieres es realmente una mala pregunta: no muestra ningún esfuerzo de tu parte y ya eso basta para que sea mal recibida en la comunidad. No obstante, tu pregunta se puede mejorar, haciendo por ejemplo lo que dice @FrancoBerardi pudiendo pasar de ser una mala pregunta a ser una buena pregunta incluso con varios votos a favor y con alguna otra buena respuesta. En cuanto a esta pregunta, también es *mala*, porque lo que planteas aquí deber ser tratado mejor en `Meta`, que es algo así como otra rama de SO para plantear dudas sobre el funcionamiento del sitio ...

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Steve, primeramente te sugerimos revisar [ask] , con esto tendrás un mejor criterio para saber como formular una pregunta en el sitio, no te desesperes yo al inicio también sufrí algunos cierres de preguntas. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio, un saludo y bienvenido!

Comment: el puntuar negativo significa que no esta bien formulada la pregunta, eres bienvenido solo debes recordar Como Preguntar, digamos que esas son las reglas del juego y muchas personas te invitan a respetarla

Comment: Lo de _con ello no puedo hacer más preguntas por un determinado lapso de tiempo_ indica que no es la primera pregunta que te cierran, pues es un bloqueo que se activa cuando hay una serie de preguntas mal recibidas. Dicho lo cual, celebro que pares un momento para reflexionar sobre qué puede estar mal, tomar nota y hacer [unas ediciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/236373/revisions) que la dejan mucho mejor. ¡Éxito y adelante, tienes un gran futuro por delante!

Comment: hey @Steve, con el puntaje que tienes, puedes entrar a la sala de chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol ahí podemos conversar sobre cómo sería un buen roadmap para ti. Saludos y bienvenido al mundo del desarrollo :D

Comment: Porque en este sitio a todo el mundo le encanta borrarte las preguntas. Simple

Comment: Mejor tener el sitio con un contenido claro y preciso con preguntas y respuestas que puedan ayudar a cualquier usuario en el futuro,que tener el sitio con muchísimas preguntas que algunas no se les puede coger ni con pinzas, otras están en ingles y otros que creen que están en yahoo respuestas,
Si se borran preguntas es porque no tienen validez en el sitio, estan mal formuladas y/o no cumplen las reglas de [ask] y [answer].

Answer (score 3):

Lo pongo como respuesta porque mi comentario se estaba haciendo muy largo.

Primero quiero darte la bienvenida a Meta, segundo felicitarte por haberte tomado el tiempo de leer los enlaces de ayuda y mejorar tu pregunta de acuerdo a ellos.

Con respecto a tu pregunta **siento que pedir definiciones está fuera del alcance** de [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) ya que eso fácilmente se encuentra en Wikipedia o cualquier recurso en linea.
Por otro lado, hacer una pregunta como *¿Cuál es la diferencia entre objeto e instancia?* siento que **si** puede ir dentro del alcance del sitio.

**¿Por qué?**
Lo dice el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour):

> Con tu ayuda, trabajamos juntos para crear una biblioteca de respuestas detalladas para todas las preguntas sobre programación, desarrollo y uso de software.

Una pregunta como ***¿Cuál es la diferencia entre objeto e instancia?*** tiene que ver con programación e incluso tiene el potencial de convertirse en una pregunta canónica con una que otra excelente respuesta.

Y eso lo podemos ver si hacemos una [pequeña búsqueda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=diferencia%20entre%20is%3aquestion) en el sitio principal, incluso pondré unos ejemplos

- [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre String y string?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-string-y-string) (37 puntos hasta la fecha)
- [¿Cual es la diferencia entre static y final?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49967/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-static-y-final) (20 puntos hasta la fecha, y a mi parecer una pregunta muy pobre en cuanto a su desarrollo pero con una excelente respuesta)
- [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre echo, print, print_r, var_dump y var_export en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72719/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-echo-print-print-r-var-dump-y-var-export-en-php) (51 puntos hasta la fecha)
- [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un inner y un outer join?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-un-inner-y-un-outer-join) (84 puntos hasta la fecha)

Solo por mencionar algunas, en tres de ellas no veo código, ni un ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable y aún así obtuvieron respuestas de gran calidad

Por último, para responder a tu pregunta **¿Qué hago para que la comunidad de desarrolladores no me reciba mal?**

Mis recomendaciones serían:

- Leer y aplicar las reglas (lo hiciste y de nuevo te felicito por ello)
- Siempre mantén el respeto y el trato cordial, recuerda que todos aquí estamos voluntariamente (no nos pagan por estar aquí)

Comment: Son todas preguntas muy viejas.. y las reglas fueron cambiando respecto de algunos puntos ;)

Comment: @gbianchi ¿qué me dices de [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript) hecha en el 2018? A mi parecer el OP mejoró mucho su pregunta y si se limita a _¿Cuál es la diferencia entre objeto e instancia?_ beneficiaría mucho al sitio

Comment: no hablo de esta. Fijate que deje dos comentarios en la pregunta. Hablaba de tus ejemplos...

Comment: Ah! Entonces como siempre estamos hablando de lo mismo :P

Comment: Puse esas de ejemplo porque quería llegar al punto que preguntas básicas a veces traen grandes respuestas

Comment: Ah si si.. a veces si.. pero en otras, son basicas porque nos ponemos de acuerdo para escribirlas y explicar los conceptos...

Comment: Cuando es el propio autor de la pregunta es quién la responde, creo que podemos ser un poco más "indulgentes" a la hora de calificar la pregunta en sí. Al menos no podemos invocar "que el op no demuestra ningún esfuerzo".